# Checkers board in Java

Tags: java

As a class we were creating a checkers board in eclipse. I came up with this code but instead of displaying a checkers board it has only three white boxes and the rest is black. 
here is my code:

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class checkgame extends GraphicsProgram 
{
    private static final int ROWS = 8;

    private static final int COLUMS = 8;

    public void run()
    {
        int sqSize = getHeight() / ROWS;
        for (int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<COLUMS; j++)
            {
                int x = j*sqSize;
                int y = i*sqSize;
                GRect sq = new GRect (x,y,sqSize,sqSize);
                sq.setFilled(((i+j)/2)!=0);
                add(sq);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas where I went wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess but change your setFilled((i+j)%2 != 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
((i+j)/2)!=0
```

you want to use

```
((i+j)%2)!=0
```

Your initial expression is exactly three times true (0,0 / 0,1 / 1,0), that is why you see three white boxes. The corrected version depends on whether (i+j)/2 is odd or even - the modulo operator is the common choice in such cases.